# Missing commits when using 'git subtree split'

Tags: git, git-subtree

I had a task which is about extracting a folder from a repo and create a repo with the history of the folder extracted. I've searched the internet and I found people talking about `git subtree` and I used it as follows : 
`git subtree split -P <PATH_TO_FOLDER> -b BRANCH_NAME`

After finishing the process, I found that the commits in the branch created less than the commits when I `git log PATH_TO_FOLDER` and I don't know why this happens.

Is there any way to do this without missing any commits?

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522392/how-to-copy-specific-files-from-one-git-repo-to-another-preserving-history/55523006#55523006

Comment: `git log BRANCH_NAME..HEAD -- PATH_TO_FOLDER` should give you the commits that affect `PATH_TO_FOLDER` and are _not_ in `BRANCH_NAME` (the extracted history) but _are_ in your current branch; in other words, you should get the extra commits. What do you see?

Comment: @MikeFaber Thank you for your response, but it will take forever to only move one folder from the original repo.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio I tried this command but it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew what was wrong.

There was a branch that's not merged into the master branch -which causes some commits to be missing after executing `git subtree`-, and after many trials I found that `git subtree` is working on a single branch not the whole repository so I merged the last branch to the master branch and executing it again and it worked.